# Kafka topic - schema registry compatibility

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have v001 version topic and v001-value schema subject.
I made a breaking change in schema, where some optional fields are made mandatory.
Although, messages in kafka before this change have this all fields. Whether I have to create new topic for this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Schema Registry will tell you if you have an incompatible schema, depending on how you have it configured.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#post--compatibility-subjects-(string-%20subject)-versions-(versionId-%20version)

> have to create new topic for this change

Not necessarily, you could delete the schema in the registry, then push on a new one.

Comment: My question was different.

Comment: I want to know whether existing messages in topic will be compatible with new schema? Since I have only optional field to mandatory change.

Comment: I understood your question and I am telling you that you can take that new schema, and check it. Or you can push those messages, and if it doesn't fail, then this same API call will succeed because the same code is ran on the registry server